# jQuery hide/show a div containing Highcharts

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, firefox, highcharts

I want to `hide/show` a div that contains highcharts. 
In chrome and Safari I'm able to successfully hide the div while in Firefox, the imprints of the highcharts get remained. 
Here is my [jsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/zkbb4/). Try opening this link in Chrome and Firefox.
How do I hide the highcharts in Firefox?

Comment: Any reason why you're using ```.css('visibility','hidden')``` instead of ```.hide()```? The latter works in all browsers.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zkbb4/1/

Comment: Yes. I want to just want to make that div invisible, since I dont want my footer to come up when hiding the container div.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that Highcharts uses SVG to render charts, so CSS `style="visibility: hidden"` doesn't work. Instead you need to set attribute `visibility = "hidden"`. Simple example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/f2SDB/

```
$("#hide").click(function () {
    $('#container *').attr('visibility', 'hidden');
    $('#container').css('visibility', 'hidden');
});
$("#show").click(function () {
    $('#container *').attr('visibility', 'visible');
    $('#container').css('visibility', 'visible');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

i could not find the reason behind it not working in firefox.

To make it work according to your requirement, i have created  fiddle for same.

**[Link To Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zkbb4/3/)**

Wrap the container div inside outer div. Give same css of that of container div to parent div. Now even if you hide the container using `.hide()` or `display:none` , the height and width will be preserved and footer will not be coming up.